# How to remove dust from clothing without washing?

Tags: cleaning, clothing, dust

I recently cut something out using a [Dremel Saw](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dremel-3000-Series-Multitool-Accessories/dp/B0078LENZC) and as some of you may know - these can get dust everywhere. I wasn't using any sort of extractor fan to remove the dust while sawing so it was free to fall anywhere and everywhere, including my nice black trousers.

I tried patting it out with my hands as well as rubbing (forgot to wash them the first time so it just made things worse) and that's got some of the larger quantities of dust off of them but they're still visibly dusty and unclean. I have also tried wetting my hands and rubbing which works for a short while until it dries again and then the dust is still there - just hard to see when wet!

**Does anyone know any methods of removing stubborn dust particles from trousers or any other item of clothing?**

This has also happened previously with a nice woollen jumper when I was sanding down a table and I was forced to wash it to get it clean again; however, I have just washed these trousers so would prefer a method that didn't require me to wash them again (although I fear that this is inevitable)

*In case it helps any answers, I was cutting out bits of PCB board produced by [SpiritCircuits](http://www.spiritcircuits.com/services/go-naked) and this is what is covering my legs.*

Comment: Related: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/15895/6973.  Those answers would work here too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The lowly adhesive lint brush does wonders. Also, in a pinch I've used masking tape wrapped sticky-side-out around my hand to tackle both.

Comment: duct tape is even better for this. it can be used to get really fine dust out of densely-formed felt hats.

Answer (score 6):

I'd have vacuumed them with the upholstery nozzle, but now that you've dampened the dust with wet hands, it may not work, in which case, you'll have to wash them again.

Answer (score 4):

Compressed air works really well but this is only an option if you have an air compressor. I wouldn't use the cans because they are expensive and the freon inside can make things worse.

Comment: Ah I was going to say I have canned air available at my place of work but read further so that's a no go!

Answer (score 4):

In days of yore people would hang garments, curtains, rugs and other fabric items up and beat them. Beating loosened the dust which would fall or be blown away on the breeze.

This method is rather messy though and doesn't collect the dust, so if you have a suitable vacuum cleaner then Bamboo's method is better.

Answer (score 0):

Use a bounce dryer sheet! 
They double as tack cloths as well

Comment: Welcome to Lifehacks! This is a great idea, but it doesn't seem to have enough detail. Would you be able to expand a bit on _how_ and/or _why_ the Bounce sheets would work? Thanks!